# Dash deployed on apache server failing with "Dash object not callable"

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, plotly-dash

I'm trying to deploy a python dash app to my apache server. I followed the scant amount of information about this configuration that I could find ([officials docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/); [this troubleshooting thread was a bit better](https://community.plotly.com/t/deploy-dash-on-apache-server-solved/4855)). When I visit the website, the page returns a `500 Internal Server Error`, which is described as `"Dash object not callable"` in the server error log. These are the config files:

```
>> cat /var/www/html/wsgi/dashGAF.wsgi
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/ubuntu/dashboards/")
from dashGAF import app as application
```

```
>> cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/dash.conf 
WSGIDaemonProcess dashGAF user=ubuntu group=ubuntu home=/home/ubuntu threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /dashGAF /var/www/html/wsgi/dashGAF.wsgi
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/dashboards>
        WSGIProcessGroup dashGAF
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            WSGIScriptReloading On
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

```
>> cat dashGAF.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, routes_pathname_prefix='/dashGAF/')
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I visit my dash app at `the_ip_address/dashGAF`, I get a `500 Internal Server Error`. Inspecting the error.log I see:

```
[Sat Jun 20 04:42:59.502528 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6064:tid 140622992238336] [client 118.210.193.245:50042] mod_wsgi (pid=6064): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgi/dashGAF.wsgi'.
[Sat Jun 20 04:42:59.502675 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6064:tid 140622992238336] [client 118.210.193.245:50042] TypeError: 'Dash' object is not callable
```

Any help in fixing this issue would be GREATLY appreciated! Also any suggestions for changes to the configuration files would be helpful.

Some more details:

- I was getting a module import error, such as the below in my /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Sat Jun 20 03:38:58.556219 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 583:tid 140297735726848] [client 118.210.193.245:55574]   File "/home/ubuntu/dashboards/dashGAF.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sat Jun 20 03:38:58.556265 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 583:tid 140297735726848] [client 118.210.193.245:55574]     import dash
[Sat Jun 20 03:38:58.556285 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 583:tid 140297735726848] [client 118.210.193.245:55574] ImportError: No module named dash
```

Which I was able to fix by doing a `sudo pip install dash==1.13.2`.

- I have made all *.py and *.wsgi files `-rwxr-xr-x`
- I enabled the site config with `sudo a2ensite dash.conf` and reloaded config with `udo systemctl reload apache2`.
- I believe the version of python being run is python2.7 (based on the apache error.log); Not sure exactly how to specify 2.7 or 3.
- If I edit the dashGAF.wsgi to have `from dashGAF import server as application` I get a 500 Internal error, but with the following details in the server log:

```
[Sun Jun 21 06:33:28.181450 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 12237:tid 139670549669632] [client 118.210.193.245:52221] mod_wsgi (pid=12237): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgi/dashGAF.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 21 06:33:28.181512 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 12237:tid 139670549669632] [client 118.210.193.245:52221] mod_wsgi (pid=12237): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgi/dashGAF.wsgi'.
[Sun Jun 21 06:33:28.181545 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 12237:tid 139670549669632] [client 118.210.193.245:52221] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 21 06:33:28.181577 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 12237:tid 139670549669632] [client 118.210.193.245:52221]   File "/var/www/html/wsgi/dashGAF.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Jun 21 06:33:28.181685 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 12237:tid 139670549669632] [client 118.210.193.245:52221]     from dashGAF import server as application
[Sun Jun 21 06:33:28.181714 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 12237:tid 139670549669632] [client 118.210.193.245:52221] ImportError: cannot import name server
```

**Possibly there is a useful detail in the bit where it says "Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgi/dashGAF.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module." ??**

- If I edit the dashGAF.wsgi to have `application = app.server` I get a 404 Not Foun:

```
from dashGAF import app
application = app.server
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've hesitated a little bit on whether I should answer my own question. @emher 's answer was part of the problem - but not the whole solution. I needed to fix a few problems, and much of that troubleshooting was guided by @GrahamDumpleton on [github](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/585). I'm more than happy for him to provide the answer if he wants.

Nevertheless, here are the problems and fixes that needed to occur:

**problems and fixes:**

- Target the Flask server as @emher suggested with `from dashGAF import server as application`
- it is not necessary to include a `routes_pathname_prefix`, which was resolving the dashboard to [https://ip.address/dashGAF/dashGAF`](https://ip.address/dashGAF/dashGAF%60)
- the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/dash.conf` could be significantly shortened` (see below)
- There was a failed request for `_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/dash_renderer.dev.js`, and I had to add `requests_pathname_prefix='/dashGAF/'` option to my `app = dash.Dash` line ([see link on github](https://community.plotly.com/t/mod-wsgi-and-dash-virtual-host-configuration/28687))

**final setup:**

/etc/apache2/sites-available/dash.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess dashGAF user=ubuntu group=ubuntu home=/home/ubuntu threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /dashGAF /var/www/html/wsgi/dashGAF.wsgi

WSGIProcessGroup dashGAF
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

/var/www/html/wsgi/dashGAF.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/ubuntu/dashboards/")
from dashGAF import server as application
```

dashboards/dashGAF.py
As above, but include:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, requests_pathname_prefix='/dashGAF/')
server = app.server
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. This really helped me out!

Answer (score 4):

Typically, you would target the Flask server rather than the Dash app in the wsgi script. That is, instead of

```
from dashGAF import app as application
```

it should be

```
from dashGAF import server as application
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... But if I edit my *.wsgi script to `import server`, I get a 404 Not Found error for that page. Have edited my post accordingly...

Comment: I've tested again, and this time I get a different error (not a 404 Not Found). It looks like it's not reading my wsgi file correctly. I'm not sure why I didn't get this the first time. I wonder if I should be doing a `systemctl reload apache2` with each change to the wsgi file?