# How do I host a Dash app on an Apache Server?

Tags: python, apache, raspberry-pi, plotly-dash

I'm new to hosting a Raspberry Pi Apache server and I have a simple [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com) application I would like to host via a .wsgi file. Following Flask's [official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62481788/dash-deployed-on-apache-server-failing-with-dash-object-not-callable) post's answer, modwsgi's [documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIProcessGroup.html), and [this](https://www.thegeeksearch.com/setup-flask-with-apache-and-wsgi/) guide for connecting Flask to Apache; I was able to get my files and structure to the state it is in below, but navigating to http://#.#.#.#/dash returns a 404, while http://#.#.#.# navigates to the default Apache page. I'm sure I am missing something and that it is relatively straight forward, I'm just not sure what. The apache error log has no errors or abnormalities.

### dash.py

```py
from datetime import date
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

import data_controller as dc

external_stylesheets = ['/style.css']

data = dc.Data()

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, requests_pathname_prefix='/dash/')
server = app.server

def serve_layout():
    data = dc.Data()

    today = date.today()

    df = data.display_data()

    return dcc.Tabs([
        html.H1([children='Hello Apache!']),
        dash_table.DataTable(columns=[{'name':i,'id':i} for i in df.columns],data=df.loc[:].to_dict('records'))
    ])

app.layout = serve_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

### /etc/apache2/sites-available/dash.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess dash user=pi group=pi home=/home/pi/Documents/programming/ threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /dash /var/www/html/wsgi/dash.wsgi

WSGIProcessGroup dash
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

### /var/www/html/wsgi/dash.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/pi/Documents/programming/dashboard/')
from dash import server as application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, the answer was very simple, just not obvious in the resources I used. [This](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/serving-a-python-flask-web-application-via-apache-webserver-in-raspberry-pi/) walkthrough reminded me that I need to establish a virtual path between `a2ensite` and my .config file using the command `sudo /usr/sbin/a2ensite dash.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and have created a customized virtual enviroment.

First I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

While in the Folder

```
sudo chown -R www-data *
sudo chmod -R 775 *
```

For a multi page app, I tried to do as minimun as possible, i just copy and paste this code: https://dash.plotly.com/urls:

Then customize the files:

**app.py**

Located in a folder /var/www/html/Dash

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import dash

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = Dash(__name__, 
           external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,
           use_pages=True,
           requests_pathname_prefix='/Dash/')

server = app.server
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.css.config.serve_locally = True

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Multi-page app with Dash Pages'),

    html.Div(
        [
            html.Div(
                dcc.Link(
                    f"{page['name']} - {page['path']}", href=page["relative_path"]
                )
            )
            for page in dash.page_registry.values()
        ]
    ),

    dash.page_container
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,  port='8050')
```

**dash.conf**

Located in a folder /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 10.0.10.10
    ServerAdmin user@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Dash

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess Dash threads=5 user=www-data group=www-data python-path=/home/user/env/pweb/lib/python3.8/site-packages python-home=/home/user/env/pweb

    WSGIScriptAlias /Dash /var/www/html/Dash/wsgi.py

    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>

    <Directory /var/www/html/Dash>
            AddHandler wsgi-script .py
            WSGIProcessGroup Dash
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            WSGIScriptReloading On
            Allow from all
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Right after

```
a2ensite dash
```

**wsgi.py**
Located in a folder /var/www/html/Dash

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/Dash/")
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/user/env/pweb/lib/python3.8/site-packages")
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/user/env/pweb")

from app import server as application
```

To track problems while running I ran the commands:

```
tail -200 /var/log/apache2/error.log
systemctl status apache2.service
```